# Realm model stores no data while running unittests

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, realm, xctest

I'm trying to test my Swift 1.2 App using iOS 8.x and Xcode 6.4. Quick/ Nimble are used in my tests.
Right now there's a problem with my Realm Model: my test *always* fails, regardless what I try to insert into it - there's no data in it.

I've started with an in- memory realm (without success) and later switched to an on-disk realm, but again, without success.

I inspected the on-disk realm with the Realm Browser, but the Realm table had no records. The simulator had also the corresponding realm files in the `tmp` or in the `documents dir`.

My tests look like this:

```
import Quick
import Nimble

import RealmSwift
import MyDemoApp 

class TestBuilder: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        var realm: Realm!

        describe("") {
            beforeEach {
                realm = Realm(inMemoryIdentifier: "test")
            }

            it("something ") {
                let builder = SummaryBuilder(realm: realm)
                builder.build()
                expect(realm.objects(StatSummary).count).toEventually(equal(1)) // This test fails. The realm has 0 objects.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The structure that I would like to test is this one:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

public struct SummaryBuilder {

 private var realm: Realm!
 public init(realm: Realm = Realm()) {
    self.realm = realm
}
 public func build() -> Void {
        realm.write {
            let summary = StatSummary()
        }
    }
}
```

Switching from the `write` closure to the implicit transactions (`beginTransaction()` / `commitTransaction()`) gave me no success.

Realm and Quick/Nimble are integrated using Cocoapods. The podfile is:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'RealmSwift'


def testing_pods
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Quick', '~> 0.3.0'
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 1.0.0'
end

target 'MyDemoAppTest' do
    testing_pods
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did not **add** the StatSummary object to the Realm at all. You should **add** any object to store to the Realm database. Like following:

```
realm.write {
    let summary = StatSummary()
    realm.add(summary) // You should add object to realm
}
```

Please see also writes section of the documentation. https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#adding-objects